# How do I access properties of checked out files in Vault Client?

Tags: c#, sourcegear-vault

I'm developing a WinForms application with SourceGear's Vault Client .NET API

I want to get more information of files that are checked out. 
The code below loops through each file of checkouts.

Problem: the only (file) properties I can access are FileId and CheckOutUsers.

Expectation: I need to get File Name and additional info if available.

```
VaultClientCheckOutList chList = ServerOperations.ProcessCommandListCheckOuts();
foreach (var item in chList.Cast<VaultClientCheckOutItem>().ToList())
{
   list.Add(item.FileID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a tag to this to explain what system you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is the solution
The first foreach-loop is to iterate over the checked out items.
To access the files of a checked out item I had iterate over CheckOutUsers peroperty (second foreach-loop).

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
VaultClientCheckOutList chList = ServerOperations.ProcessCommandListCheckOuts();
foreach (var item in chList.Cast<VaultClientCheckOutItem>().ToList())
{
    foreach (var file in item.CheckOutUsers)
        list.Add(file.LocalPath);
}
```